# How to make a text in a div responsive?

Tags: mobile, text

I am having 5 divs with 2-3 lines text on each. But in mobile version it is showing as in length and i want to make it in lines as it is going responsive.

Please lighten me up in this regard

Thanks

TeekeyBee

```
.article_left_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}

.article_left2_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_03.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.article_left3_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_05.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.article_right_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_02.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;

}

.article_right2_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_04.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.article_right3_bg {
    background-image: url(images/article_bg_06.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.article_title, .article_title1, .article_title2 {
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    }

.article_title h2 {
    margin:20px 0 5px 0;
    color:#000;
    font-size:25px; 
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 50px 0 0 58px;
    }

.article_title1 h2 {
    margin:20px 0 5px 0;
    color:#000;
    font-size:25px; 
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 90px 0 0 58px;
    }

.article_title2 h2 {
    margin:20px 0 5px 0;
    color:#000;
    font-size:25px; 
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 60px 0 0 68px;
    }


.article_title h2 a, .article_title1 h2 a, .article_title2 h2 a{
    color:#000}


.article_title .subtitle, .article_title1 .subtitle {
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#000;
    padding: 0 0 0 58px;
    }

.article_title2 .subtitle {
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#000;
    padding: 0 0 0 68px;

}

.article_descr {
    width: 290px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 0 0 58px;
    }

.article_item .link_more,
.article_item .link_more:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:25px;
    background:url(images/arrow_right.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left:45px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;}
```

Comment: can you share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have uploaded the css which i am used to make responsive

Answer (score 0):

If you set your font-size in relative units instead of absolute units it should solve your problem:

```css
.article_item .link_more,
.article_item .link_more:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:25px;
    background:url(images/arrow_right.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left:45px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:.3vw;
    color:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="article_item">
  I am some text
 </div>
```